# How to simplify equation in Mathematica?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I would like to know how can I simplify the following:
[image]

in Mathematica.

Comment: It will help people help you if you copy and paste your expression from Mathematica into the question.  Also nice to see what you have tried already.

Comment: About as simple as you'll get:  $$\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}-\sqrt{\frac{1}{\tan ^4\left(\frac{\theta }{2}\right)+\cot
   ^4\left(\frac{\theta }{2}\right)+2}}}$$

Comment: For ` (0 < \[Theta] < Pi/2)`  you can tweak  the result of @Rudy Potter's to `Cos[\[Theta]]/Sqrt[1 + Cos[\[Theta]]^2]`

Answer (score 3):

I would try `FullSimplify[TrigToExp[`*yourfunction*`]]`

Now that you have been sufficiently flogged for not typing out your input...

```
FullSimplify[
 TrigToExp[
  Sin[ArcCos[(Sqrt[2/(1 + Tan[\[Theta]/2]^4)] + Sqrt[2/(
       1 + Tan[\[Theta]/2]^-4)])/2]]]]
```

gives
`Sqrt[1/2 - Sqrt[Sin[\[Theta]]^4/(3 + Cos[2 \[Theta]])^2]]`
and

```
FullSimplify[
 Sin[ArcCos[(Sqrt[2/(1 + Tan[\[Theta]/2]^4)] + Sqrt[2/(
      1 + Tan[\[Theta]/2]^-4)])/2]]]
```

gives`Sqrt[1/2 - Sqrt[1/(2 + Cot[\[Theta]/2]^4 + Tan[\[Theta]/2]^4)]]`

as  Andreas suggests, you can do:

```
Assuming[{-(Pi/2) <=  \[Theta], \[Theta] <=  Pi/2}, 
 FullSimplify[
  TrigToExp[
   Sin[ArcCos[(Sqrt[2/(1 + Tan[\[Theta]/2]^4)] + 
        Sqrt[2/(1 + Tan[\[Theta]/2]^-4)])/2]]]]]
```

to get `(Sqrt[2] Cos[\[Theta]])/Sqrt[3 + Cos[2 \[Theta]]]`
which is pretty compact and appears to be true from -Pi/2 to +Pi/2